# Pytest Reports logging duplicate entries

Tags: pytest, report

I am using the following static method to generate the report using the Pytest framework

```
import logging
import os

class LogGen:
    @staticmethod
    def setup_logger(log_file_path="./logs/automation.log", log_level=logging.INFO):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(log_file_path), exist_ok=True)

        formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(module)s:%(lineno)d:%(message)s",
                                      datefmt="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_path)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(log_level)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        logger.addHandler(console_handler)

        return logger
```

In my actual testcase I am using the above by doing the following:

```
from utilities.customLogger import LogGen
```

then inside my test class I am doing:

```
logger = LogGen.setup_logger()
```

and at the relevant points in my test case I am doing:

```
self.logger.info("********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********")
self.logger.info("********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********")
```

etc.

I run my test from the pycharm terminal by giving the following command:

```
pytest -v -m "sanity" --html=./Reports/report.html testCases --browser safari
```

The report that gets generated has Captured stderr call' section that looks like the following:

```
------------------------------Captured stderr call------------------------------ 
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:30:********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:39 PM:INFO:test_verify_footer:31:********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:35:****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
09/28/2023 02:28:44 PM:INFO:cookie_consent:37:****** Cookie banner found.***********
```

.
.
.
...and so on.

below that, I have the Captured log call that looks like this:

```
-------------------------------Captured log call-------------------------------- 
INFO     root:test_sticky_footer.py:30 ********* Test_003_customerFooter ***********
INFO     root:test_sticky_footer.py:31 ********* Verifying customer Footer is loaded and displayed ***********
INFO     root:cookie_consent.py:35 ****** the cookie banner is expected.***********
INFO     root:cookie_consent.py:37 ****** Cookie banner found.***********
```

.
.
...and so on.

I am not interested in the log under the 'Captured stderr call' in my report as it seems useless with multiple duplicate entries. All I am interested in is the log under the 'Captured log call'. I am not sure how to do it. Need some help here.